# Move referenced files in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, shutil

I have dictionary in Python that includes the present and the desired path of a file.

```
files = {
    'C:\\Users\\a\\A\\A.jpg': 'C:\\Users\\a\\A\\test_a\\A.jpg',
    'C:\\Users\\a\\B\\B.jpg': 'C:\\Users\\a\\B\\test_a\\B.jpg',
    'C:\\Users\\a\\C\\C.jpg': 'C:\\Users\\a\\test_a\\C.jpg'
}
```

How can I use the items of the map as the arguments of the `shutil.move()` function? I tried several ways without success.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? What did you expect to happen for the key-value pairs? Does `for source, dest in files.items(): shutil.move(source, dest)` cover it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
for frm,to in files.items():
    shutil.move(frm,to)
```

You simply iterate over the `(key,value)` tuples of the dictionary, and call the [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) function on these.

The only problem I see is that you perhaps need to construct the *directory* first: otherwise moving the object might fail. You can do this by first detecting the [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname), detect if the directory exists and if not create such directory:

```
#only if you are not sure the directory exists
for frm,to in files.items():
    directory = os.path.dirname(to)
    os.makedirs(directory,exist_ok=True) #create a directory if it does not exists
    shutil.move(frm,to)
```